# Create wrap for each object and insert it's key+values into that wrap jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I wrap each object and then insert into each of created wrap the object's indexes and values?

I've tried to achieve this with this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "some url",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
    var data = data._embedded.video;
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
      $('.list').append('<div class="video_wrap ' + value.id + '"></div>');
      $.each(value, function (i, v) {
        $('.video_wrap').append('<div>' + i + ': ' + v + '</div>');
      });
    });

  }
});
```

Must look like this:

```
<div class="list">
 <div class="video_wrap 497">
  <div>id: 497<div>
  <div>name: smth<div>
 </div>
 <div class="video_wrap 514">
  <div>id: 514<div>
  <div>name: smth<div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But instead I got this:

```
<div class="list">
 <div class="video_wrap 497">
  <div>id: 497<div>
  <div>name: smth<div>
  <div>id: 514<div>
  <div>name: smth<div>
 </div>
 <div class="video_wrap 514">
   <div>id: 497<div>
   <div>name: smth<div>
   <div>id: 514<div>
   <div>name: smth<div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second loop updates all instances of `.video_wrap`:

```
$('.video_wrap').append(
```

You can change this so that it only updates the one you're interested in:

```
$('.video_wrap.' + value.id).append(
```

---

Alternatively, keep a record of the new `video_wrap` and use that directly:

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
  var wrap = $('<div class="video_wrap ' + value.id + '">').appendTo(".list");
  $.each(value, function (i, v) {
    wrap.append('<div>' + i + ': ' + v + '</div>');
  });
});
```

here, `appendTo` will return the item being appended, wile `append` will return the parent item.